# RSpec: Force error within negated custom matcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a custom matcher, that has an `expect` within:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_access_to do |action|
  match do |user|
    allow(controller).to receive(:authorize!)

    # perform GET request...

    expect(controller).to have_received(:authorize!)

    response.code == "200"
  end
end
```

This works, as long as I call it this way

```
it { expect(shop_manager).to have_access_to(:index) }
```

But when I try to use the negated form `not_to`, and the `expect` within the customer matcher fails, the test passes:

```
it { expect(shop_manager).not_to have_access_to(:index) }
```

I understand RSpec logic here: When you want the test to fail with `not_to` and it fails, everything is fine.

But this `expect` serves as a side condition: I want to check if the whole request has passed the `authorize!` step.

I know that a matcher should only test one thing, but I use it a lot and it would lead to a lot of code duplication when I add the `have_received(:authorize!)` check to every single test.

> Is there a way to force RSpec to fail, no matter if the call is negated or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_access_to do |action|
  match do |user|
    allow(controller).to receive(:authorize!)

    # perform GET request...
    fail "failed to receive authorize" unless controller.received_message?(:authorize!)

    response.code == "200"
  end
end
```

Using old rspec shoulda syntax. However, I get a deprecation warning for this

> Using `received_message?` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated.